# Guess the Disney song from the initials number 7

Tags: music

OK this on should be easy.
I G B A M K S E B
W I N S A K O B W Q S L H
I G B A M E L N K W B
I B U O L D I W O M R
T F A R U T
O I J C W T B K

Comment: Please do not solicit upvotes. If people like your puzzles they will vote them up without being asked. And the scores are meant to represent "how much did people like this puzzle?" not some combination of that and "how much did the poster beg for upvotes".

Comment: @gareth mccaughanOk Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this

> "I Just Can't Wait to be King" from the Lion King?

Comment: Spot on! Well done